# Guest account doesn't show on switch user screen in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, user-accounts

I just set the password for the Guest account (changed the name of it too), but when I go to the "Switch User" screen, the Guest account is not shown as an option (neither as "Guest" nor with the new name).

How then do I switch to using the Guest account?

Guest account is enabled.

OS: Windows Vista Ultimate SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure `Guest` is in the `Guests` group.
- Make sure `Guest` is allowed to login:

  `secpol.msc` → *Local policies → User Rights Assignment → Deny logon locally*
- Make sure neither of the names is in the "Special accounts" list:

  `regedit` → `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList`